# how to create SubDomains on localhost

Tags: apache, xampp, subdomain

i have changed this in my httpd.conf file

```
#Listen 1234
```

and made 2 virtualhost in my http.vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.5:1234>
 DocumentRoot "D:/SVN data/WebClient_PHP/trunk/current_project_re/public"
 ServerName prod
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.6:1234>
  DocumentRoot "D:/SVN data/WebClient_PHP/trunk/current_project_dec/public"
  ServerName dev
</VirtualHost>
```

also changed this in my host file in windows/system32/drivers/etc/host

```
127.0.0.5:1234 prod

127.0.0.6:1234 dev
```

after restarting my apache when i point to "dev" or "prod" both are not working

Answer (score 0):

You are sure, both addresses point to your local machine?

If not, you just may use 127.0.0.1 in both files and let apache handle the document root, specified by your ServerName.

Oh, and remove the port declaration in the hosts file

Comment: i write this in my browser http://127.0.0.5:1234/ and it point me to my localhost